# How can we delete record of a table when record of another table deleted using function, trigger in postgresql -concepts

Tags: postgresql, triggers

How can we  delete record of a table when record of another table deleted using function, trigger in postgresql -concepts?

Answer (score 1):

Use "ON DELETE CASCADE" on the column definition.  Something like this will do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_carts (
    id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
   ,cart_name  varchar NOT NULL
 );


CREATE TABLE cart_items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
   ,cart_id INT REFERENCES shopping_carts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
   ,item_description varchar NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a foreign key constraint then use a cascading delete (assuming this exists in postgresql, I don't know).